# Proving that $a_n=\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$ converges, finding its limit and showing that its sequence ${(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}}$ is monotinic.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta, monotone-functions

As the title says, below I've proved the statement. Just posted here for verification and correction! And of course for other people to be inspired.

Let $a_n=\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Show that $a_n$ converges as $n\to\infty$ find its limit, and show that the sequence ${(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}}$ is monotinic.

***Proof:***

For **convergence**, we look for:

$\forall_{\epsilon\gt0}\exists_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{n\gt N}(|a_n-l|<\epsilon) \iff l-\epsilon<a_n<l+\epsilon.$ If this property holds for one and only one $l$, then $a_n$ convergence with its limit being unique.

$l-\epsilon<\sqrt{n^2+n}-n<l+\epsilon \iff (l+n-\epsilon)^2<n^2+n<(l+n+\epsilon)^2 \iff $

$n(n+l-\epsilon)+l(n+l-\epsilon)-\epsilon(n+l-\epsilon) <n^2+n< $
$n(n+l+\epsilon)+l(n+l+\epsilon)+\epsilon(n+l+\epsilon)$

$\epsilon$ can get randomly small, so it can be ommited for large $n$. Then;

$n(n+l)+l(n+l)<n^2+n< n(n+l)+l(n+l) \iff$ 
$n^2+2ln+l^2<n^2+n<n^2+2ln+l^2.$

As $n\to\infty$, all terms not containing $n$ can be omitted as they are unimpactfully small. Then;

$n^2+2ln<n^2+n<n^2+2ln \iff 2ln<n<2ln \iff n=2ln \iff l=\frac{1}{2}.$

This property only holds for one $l$, so $a_n$ is convergent, and with this, its limit $l=\frac{1}{2}$ has also been found.

For **monotonity** we look for:

$\forall_n(\sqrt{(n+1)^2+(n+1)}-(n+1)>\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)$.

For all $n$:

$1>0 \iff 4n^2+4n+1>4n^2+4n \iff (2n+1)^2>4(n^2+n) \iff$
$2n+1>2\sqrt{n^2+n} \iff n^2+2n+1>n^2+2\sqrt{n^2+n} \iff$
$(n+1)^2>n^2+2\sqrt{n^2+n} \iff (n+1)^2+n+1>n^2+n+2\sqrt{n^2+n}+1 \iff$
$\sqrt{(n+1)^2+n+1}>\sqrt{n^2+n}+1 \iff\sqrt{(n+1)^2+(n+1)}-(n+1)>\sqrt{n^2+n}-n$

So the series ${(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}}$ is monotonic.

**Conclusion:**

$a_n$ converges with its unique limit being $l=\frac{1}{2}$, and the series ${(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}}$ is monotinic. $\tag*{$\Box$}$

Comment: This looks like a lot of interesting mathematics.  Is there a question?

Comment: Good one, haha. I should introduce at the start whether these proofs are correct, just a verification!

Comment: Perchance did you consider using a conjugate like $\sqrt{n^2+n}+n$ and creating a difference of squares?

Comment: 1. Several typos (missing square, wrong sign etc). 2. How can you neglect the term $\epsilon n$? Yes, $\epsilon$ is small, but fixed, however, $n\to\infty$, so the term $\epsilon n$ can become arbitrary large for any $\epsilon$. 3. $2ln<n<2ln$ does not look good.

Comment: About $\epsilon n$, I said that exact same thing to my teacher but he said it was okay and you could totally neglect $\epsilon$ as you can choose it infinitely small.

Comment: As it stands $\forall_{\epsilon\gt0}\exists_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\forall_{n\gt N}$. It means that you *first* choose (freeze) $\epsilon$ and *then* $n$ can be whatever large. You cannot think $\epsilon$ is infinitely small for a given $n$. Keep the term $\epsilon n$, the estimation you do will work with it too. After removing $n^2$ you cancel $n$ the same way you do it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "save" your calculation of $l$ like this: you have got
$$
n^2+2n(l-\epsilon)+(l-\epsilon)^2<n^2+n<n^2+2n(l+\epsilon)+(l+\epsilon)^2.
$$
Removing $n^2$ and dividing by $n$ gives
$$
2(l-\epsilon)+\frac{(l-\epsilon)^2}{n}<1<2(l+\epsilon)+\frac{(l+\epsilon)^2}{n}.
$$
Since it has to be true for all large $n$ ($n\to\infty$) it must hold
$$
2(l-\epsilon)\le 1\le 2(l+\epsilon).
$$
Since it holds for any $\epsilon>0$ we have
$$
2l\le 1\le 2l.
$$

Comment: Isn't this basically what I did? I agree that it would be better to have $\leq$ than $\lt$, but you divide by n first, then omit $\epsilon$ where I first omit $\epsilon$ and then divide by n. How come the strict inequalities transform to $\leq$?

Comment: @Marc Again, it is not correct to neglect $\epsilon n$ as it is not small. You need to keep $\epsilon$ to the very end when $n$ disappears. Then you may take it as small as you like, but not earlier. Strict inequality becomes non-strict when you pass to the limit. For example, $5<5+\frac{1}{n}$, but $5\not<5$.

Comment: thank you very much! This certainly cleared up exactly the things I was doubting, and not really understanding. I think I've now got it down.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach: $a_n>0$,

$$a_n^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n}=\sqrt{1+n^{-1}}+1$$

is decreasing and $a_n^{-1}\to 2$. So $(a_n)$ is increasing and $a_n\to 1/2$.

Comment: However, is what I wrote down also correct, like, the logical steps etc?

Comment: @JohnWatson in the limit or monotonity proof?

Comment: @Marc Your proof of monotonicity is fine. The proof of convergence is not very rigorous. Omitting things that are small can sometimes be dangerous, although what you did here gives the correct result.

Comment: @EclipseSun I know... But I didn't really find another way out without losing formality... I've honestly tried so much at this point, but it indeed gets me the right result so I'm just sticking to this for now. Thanks for the other insights, though!

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n={n\over \sqrt{n^2+n}+n}= {1\over \sqrt{1+{1\over n}}+1}$$

so $$ 0<a_n\leq {1\over 2}$$
and since $\sqrt{1+{1\over n}}+1$ is decreasing so is $a_n$ increasing. So $a_n$ is convergent with limit ${1\over 2}$.

Comment: I think the problem with this was that I couldn't try to find the limit before proving it was convergent (even though I kind of did just that)... My teacher definitely didn't really wanna see much calculus and more of plain analysis